# Need help about contentMode and autoresizingMask of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

i have picture like this image it will present on Landscape Mode

[image]

so if rotate device to Portrait, how to present image like this

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Use an UIImageView with these settings:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like what you're trying to do is clip the image on the right, while leaving the top, left, and bottom the same.

Two things to try:

1) Subclass UIView and in the `drawRect` method, adjust the rect and draw out the clipped image using `CGContextDrawImage (context, rect, sourceImage.CGImage)`.

2) Use CALayers. You can adjust the 'contentsRect' of the imageView's layer:

```
CALayer* imageLayer = imageView.layer;
imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
CGRect rect;
if (inPortrait)
  rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0); // half size
else 
  rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); // full size
imageLayer.contentsRect = rect;
```

This slices the image in half along width. `masksToBounds` takes care of clipping sublayers (in case you have them). You can tweak the `contentsRect` unit rectangle to adjust where you want the cutoff. You may also want to adjust the imageView's own bounds as well to match the size.

This has an added bonus in that adjusting the contentsRect is automatically animated so when you do the rotation the width animates in and out nicely.

Comment: Ramin did you tell me some tutorial or example code? my code are using 
UIView and create UIImageView inside, it so complicate to convert my code to your suggestion
thanks for all help Ramin

Comment: Try option #2 above. Plug your UIImageView ivar into the first line of snippet posted above. inPortrait is a BOOL so set it to YES or NO and see if it does what you need it to do. That's probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: @Ramin, Hi I can't understand how to make image looks like content mode = Center on my layer. `x` and `y` of contentsRect is behaving strange to me. Can you add example here about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
// Set the layer contents
view.layer.contents = [image CGImage];
// Stretch so that contents overflows the edges and keeps aspect ratio
view.layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
// Clip off the overflow
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
// Set the frame
CGRect frame;
frame.origin = CGPointZero;
frame.size = view.superview.bounds.size;
view.frame = frame;
// Make sure it resizes when the superview does
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: thanks rpetrich, could you please tell me more infomation please?
i not understand about this variable image and view

Comment: i have assigen my UIImageView to view and image so it have some error like this   "_kCAGravityResizeAspectFill", referenced from:

Comment: `kCAGravityResizeAspectFill` is in QuartzCore.framework. You will need to reference it. Also, my instructions were for a `UIView` (though I don't see why they couldn't also apply to a `UIImageView`)

Comment: Also, `image` is a variable of type `UIImage` that already has the image you want loaded into it. `view` is the `UIView` you want to apply the image to.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to work with view's layer.

You can find the appropriate guidelines at https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Jim.